# Why did Yoda question Palpatine that way?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

Yoda says to Palpatine:

> Yoda: At an end your rule is. And not short enough it was. If so
> powerful you are, **why leave**?

Palpatine is not going anywhere then why did Yoda question him about leaving in this scene?

Comment: Palpatine jumps to the door to try and leave, Yoda blocks him. Yoda says it because Palpatine _was_ trying to leave.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Per the [Revenge of the Sith script:](http://imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Revenge-of-the-Sith.html)

> ["DARTH SIDIOUS flies through the air, cape flapping, heading toward
> the exit. At the last second, YODA flies into the exit and stops the
> Dark Lord]. YODA: (continuing) If so powerful you are, why leave?? -

[image]

Right before Yoda says that, Palpatine jumps for the door, and Yoda jumps to block his exit.

Comment: *But Palpatine didn’t seem entirely sure, either. Suddenly, he launched himself into the air, heading for the door. Yoda did a back flip, bounced off the wall, and reached the entrance before him. “If so powerful you are, why leave?”* - [RotS: Junior Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(junior_novelization))

Comment: Thanks, I updated the answer with the script reference!